# a Link anchors not working in mvc 3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to create a simple table of contents for a help page in an MVC 3 project. I have built the simple html table containing the links that I wish it to link to within the same page.

When I run the project and click on the link in the table, nothing happens.

Part of the table:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#filtersHelp">Filters</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <A href="#overviewHelp">Overview</A>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When any are clicked it should link to:

```
<h3 <a name="filtersHelp">Filters</a></h3>
 <p>
Lorem ipsum….
```

```
<h2 <a name="overviewHelp">Overview Tab</a></h2>
<p>
Lore, ispum….

</p>
```

I also tried replacing the `<a href>` by:

```
@Html.ActionLink()
```

but that didn't work either.

I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your h2/h3 links are not closed properly!

```
<h3> <a name="filtersHelp">Filters</a></h3>
 <p>
Lorem ipsum….
```

Comment: You are correct! I can't believe I missed that - I went over the code several times :/ Thank you so much >.<